# How to implement a .NET WebAPI with a route of "controller?action&parameters"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm trying to implement a specific HTTP interface (SAP Content Server HTTP Interface) with .NET Standard WebAPI, that requires that the routes be all in the form of:

http://server:port/somepath/controller?action&parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2...

Example:

GET

http://www.google.com/myapi/api?getStuff&stuffId=1&otherParameter=2

POST,PUT

http://www.google.com/myapi/api?putStuff&stuffId=1&otherParameter=2

Is it at all possible to do this specific routing with the action after the question mark and parameters afterwards ?

Interface specification:
https://help.sap.com/doc/b743f868cdf249cfb829a5a121cc9436/7.0/en-US/SAPHTTPInterfaceOct.pdf

Comment: I would recommend this being more RESTful: GET/PUT/POST/DELETE `http://server:port/somepath/{controller}/{id}?{parameter1}={value1}&{parameter2}={value2}...`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I access URL parameters in web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14009700/how-do-i-access-url-parameters-in-web-api)

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want the action to be a query parameter and not part of the path?  While you can change the route Template to achieve this, it's a pretty non-standard pattern that will make your life harder.

Comment: I have to conform to a standard protocol in order to integrate with SAP ArchiveLink

https://help.sap.com/doc/b743f868cdf249cfb829a5a121cc9436/7.0/en-US/SAPHTTPInterfaceOct.pdf

If not, I would be doing this the most usual way, as I know this is pretty non-standard.

Comment: I played around with a sample project and it seems that you cannot actually have a "?" in the routeTemplate.  It's not allowed by default.  I think if your action is a query parameter, then you are going to have to do some sort of custom implementation of the IHttpActionSelector interface and write your own code to select the correct action based on the first query parameter.

Comment: That's what I was not hoping for, other alternative I considered is using IIS url rewrite and transform the requests into more traditional way

Comment: @pap did you succeed ? I need to do the same

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible by [mapping your routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api):

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}?{action}&{id}&{parameter1}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

The query parameters can be added to your controller action:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id, string parameter)
{
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using url rewrite module in iis to transform the requests before reaching the api:

```
 <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="convert requests">
        <match url="^api/sapcs" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/api/sapcs/{C:1}?{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="([^&amp;]+)&amp;(.*)" />
        </conditions>
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
```